# JSF - Rich Tree CheckBox

Tags: jsf-2

I need help regarding check box tree in JSF,
Basically i have created a JSF Check Box Tree . Selecting the Node tree will select the check boxes of child Nodes and selecting a check Box of a child Node will Unselected the Parent Node .

**Problem Faced** : Now after clearing all the check boxes, if tree is collapsed and  expanded ,  the child tree nodes are getting selected .
snippet of XHTML :

```
            <rich:treeNode type="MARKET" iconCollapsed="#{MarketZone.icon}" iconExpanded="#{MarketZone.icon}" id="marketTreeID"  >
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selMarketId"  value="#{bUserMgt.marketTreeCheckMap[MarketZone.id]}" onclick="selectAllZonesForMarket(this)">
                <a4j:ajax listener="#{bUserMgt.selectedMarketValue}"/></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                 <h:outputText  value="#{MarketZone.name}" />
           </rich:treeNode>

            <rich:treeNode type="ZONE" iconCollapsed="#{MarketZone.icon}" iconExpanded="#{MarketZone.icon}" id="zoneTreeID"  >
               <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selzoneId"  value="#{bUserMgt.zoneTreeCheckMap[MarketZone.id]}" onclick="deselectAllZonesForMarket(this)" >
                <a4j:ajax listener="#{bUserMgt.selectedZoneValue}"/>
               </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                <h:outputText  value="#{MarketZone.name}"/>
           </rich:treeNode>         
        </rich:tree>
```

selectAllZonesForMarket() and deselectAllZonesForMarket() : Javascript Code function for selecting and deselecting the CheckBoxes

Can you please help in letting me know what I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use selectionMode="checkbox" in treetable it working fine according your requirement in prime faces.
go throw the link :
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableCheckbox.jsf